# Stash segment for use on other page

Tags: stash

I want to save segment_3 for use on another page for each user, I think the following should work:

```
{exp:stash:set name="selected_category_url" scope="user" save="yes"}
   {exp:streeng slug="yes" lower="yes"}
     {segment_3_category_name}
   {/exp:streeng}x
{/exp:stash:set}
```

On next page:

```
{exp:stash:get name="selected_category_url" scope="user" save="yes"}
```

But this isn't working, I've tried various mixes of 'scope' 'user' in both tags, but no luck, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the tag you are capturing is actually parsed before you try to save the variable, otherwise you will capture the literal tag pair rather than its output:

```
{exp:stash:set name="selected_category_url" scope="user" save="yes" parse="yes"}
   {exp:streeng slug="yes" lower="yes"}
     {segment_3_category_name}
   {/exp:streeng}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Get it like this:

```
{exp:stash:get name="selected_category_url" scope="user"}
```

Make sure you have `$config['stash_cookie_enabled'] = TRUE` in your config, otherwise the `user` scope will be unavailable.

Comment: still not working unfortunately.

Comment: I think I figured why this is not working, the URL is blog/category/mobile and printing the last_segment returns 'blog'! presumably that's expected behaviour?

Comment: maybe that's not why, I watched the value in the database and it's getting set once but then getting cleared

Comment: the row in the database is still there but the value is empty

Comment: I sounds like the value is getting overwritten. The template code that sets the variable should only be run on the initial page. The stash:get should only be run on the next page.